# How to fix "Ajax sending response multiple times to views.py in django? "

Tags: ajax, django, iframe

I'm passing HTML iframe source as variable to views.py via ajax response from django template but it is printing temp names as multiple times

In index.html:
Here im passing temp variable `<iframe>` tag src to ajax

```
{%for temp in temp_list%}

   <iframe src='?{{temp}}' style='display:none' onload='statusVNC(this.src)'/>

{%endfor%}
```

ajax: Here i'm passing temp_name to views.py

```
<script>
    function statusVNC(src){
        var pageurl = '/vncform/vnc_status/'; 
        var temp_name = src.split('?')[1];
        $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: pageurl,
                data: {template: temp_name}, 
                success: function (data) {
                if(data != '')
                {
                    alert(data.vnc_status)
                }
            }
        });
      }
</script>
```

in views.py: Here i'm printing request.GET where it is printing temp values mutliple times, please can u suggest how to solve it?

```
def vnc_status(request):    
    print request.GET
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='
    url(r'^templates/$', views.templates, name='templates'),
    url(r'^vnc_status/$', views.vnc_status, name='vnc_status'),
    url(r'^templates/edit/temp_name=(?P<temp_name>[\w\-]+)$', views.editTemplate, name='editTemplate')
]
```

where `temp_list = ['arun', 'kumar', 'a', 'a213']`

Comment: What is surprising about this? You have multiple items in your list, so you create multiple iframes and send multiple requests.

Comment: actually in list there are 4 items but when i run it is going on printing values